# Replace a column values from 'male' to 'female' and 'female' to 'male'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have one table, *gender*, in which only two entries are there, 'male' and 'female' number of rows with these two entries only. Now I want to write a procedure which replaces these two values and the output should be as below,

```
Input           Output

sex             sex
------------------------
male            female
female          male
female          male
male            female
```

I am creating a procedure, which gives me an error. I am using a cursor to fetch more than one row. I know that we can do it by using only one update statement, but I want to try like this.

```
declare
  v_gen gender%rowtype;
  cursor cur_gender is
    select * from gender;
begin
  open cur_gender;
  loop
    fetch cur_gender into v_gen;
    select * from gender;
    if v_gen='male'
    then
      update gender set sex='female';
    else
      update gender set sex='male';
    end if;
    exit when v_gen%notfound;
  end loop;
  close cur_gender;
end;
```

Comment: @parado PLS-00306 wrong numbers or types of arguments in call to '=' PLS-00324 cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'v_gen'

Comment: don't know the solution, but i would be very careful updating all rows as you are doing with the statement (I am assuming this isn't the intention): update gender set sex='female'. And by the way don't use sms language

Comment: What you do is the following: You look at the first row only (with your FETCH .. INTO) then you update all rows. I doubt thats intended...

Answer (score 19):

```
update Table1 set "col" = (case "col" when 'male' then 'female'
else 'male' end);
```

***[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/827b4/1)***

Comment: OP said `I knw that we can do it by using only 1 update statemen`

Answer (score 4):

```
ID   Username   Email              Gender
1    sanjay     sanjay@gmail.com   Male
2    nikky      nikky@gmail.com    Male
11   raj        raj@gmail.com      Female
12   Rahul      rahul@gmail.com    Female
```

```
update users set gender = (case when gender = 'Male' then 'Female' else 'Male' end);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with what you have. The immediate cause of the PLS-00324 is that `v_gen` is a record, so you need to compare a field with that record to your fixed value, not the whole record:

```
if v_gen='male'
```

becomes

```
if v_gen.sex = 'male'
```

You then have a spurious `select * from gender` which looks like an accident, and needs to be removed completely.

And finally you're applying `%notfound` to the record not to the cursor:

```
exit when v_gen%notfound;
```

becomes

```
exit when cur_gender%notfound;
```

Well, not really finally, because as others have noted each of your update statements is updating all rows in the table, so you'll end up with everything as either `male` or `female` depending on which row it processes last. You need to identify the specific row you want to update. One way is to query the `rowid` as part of the cursor, but there's a built-in way that is easier:

```
declare
  cursor cur_gender is
    select * from gender
    for update;
begin
  for v_gen in cur_gender
  loop
    if v_gen.sex='male' 
    then
      update gender set sex = 'female'
      where current of cur_gender;
    else
      update gender set sex = 'male'
      where current of cur_gender;
    end if;
  end loop;
end; 
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62b02/1).

Or you can simplify it a bit by using `case` instead of the `if`:

```
declare
  cursor cur_gender is
    select * from gender
    for update;
begin
  for v_gen in cur_gender
  loop
    update gender
    set sex = case v_gen.sex when 'male' then 'female' else 'male' end
    where current of cur_gender;
  end loop;
end; 
/
```

... which is getting pretty close to the single-update-statement approach that you already know about. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8884e/1) for that version.

You can read more about `for update` and `where current of` [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHHIIID).

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table 
SET    gender = CASE gender 
                  WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Female' 
                  WHEN 'Female' THEN 'Male' 
                  ELSE gender 
                END;
```

Comment: From Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd recommend using a Record instead of the FETCH:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE swap ()
IS
    CURSOR cur_gender IS   
        SELECT * FROM gender;
     rec_gender cur_gender%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
       FOR rec_gender IN cur_gender
    LOOP
       IF cur_gender%FOUND THEN    
            IF rec_gender.sex = 'male' THEN
                UPDATE gender set sex='female' 
                WHERE idgender = rec_gender.idgender;
            ELSE
                UPDATE gender set sex = 'male' 
                WHERE idgender = rec_gender.idgender;  
            END IF;
            -- COMMIT; --MAYBE?             
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END swap;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is even a simple way of doing this. You can use `DECODE` to do this in an Oracle database.

```
UPDATE GENDER SET SEX = DECODE(SEX, 'MALE', 'FEMALE', 'FEMALE', 'MALE');
```

The above query changes the sex of male to female and female to male.

Comment: That seems much better than using *for* loops(?).

Answer (score 1):

SQL query to proceed this:

```
UPDATE table SET gender =
(CASE  WHEN  gender ='male' THEN 'female' else 'male' END)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed this"?

Comment: Is this a response to another answer?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this query to update Male to Female and Female to Male.
Reference Images.

[Table data before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdLjM.png)

Syntax

```
    UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> set <COL_NAME> = (CASE <COL_NAME> WHEN '<DATA>' THEN'<DATA>' ELSE '<DATA>' END);
```

Example:

```
UPDATE users SET gender = (CASE gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Female' ELSE'Male' END);
```

[Table data after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNvzV.png)

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE swap ()
 IS
        CURSOR cur_gender IS   
        SELECT * FROM gender;
 BEGIN
        FOR rec_gender IN cur_gender
        LOOP
               IF rec_gender.sex = 'male' THEN
                     UPDATE gender set sex='female' where sex='male'; 
               ELSE
                     UPDATE gender set sex = 'male' where sex='female';
               END IF;
       END LOOP;
END swap;
```

Comment: What for do you use the cursor at all?

Comment: declare
  v_gen gender.sex%type;
  cursor cur_gender is
  select sex from gender;
  begin
    open cur_gender;
    loop
      fetch cur_gender into v_gen;
      if v_gen='male' then
        --dbms_output.put_line('It was ' ||v_gen);
      update gender set sex='female';
      elsif v_gen='female' then
        --dbms_output.put_line('It was ' ||v_gen);
      update gender set sex='male';
      end if;
      exit when cur_gender%notfound;  
      end loop;
      close cur_gender;
    end; Here it works but if 1st row is male then it sets male to all rows or vice versa, whts wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

Simple create a table, let it be *people*:

```
create table people(gender varchar2(10));

insert into people values('&gender');
```

Suppose inputs are male, female, female, male:

```
select * from people;
GENDER
    male
    female
    female
    male

select decode(gender, 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male') sex from people;
SEX
    female
    male
    male
    female
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Logic*/

SELECT Name, CASE
  WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 'Female'
  ELSE 'Male'
  END
AS "NewGender"
FROM NameGender ;

/*Here NameGender is the name of the Table*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update Employee
set Gender= case Gender when 'Male' then 'Female' when 'Female' then 'Male'
else 
Gender
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query works well in [Amazon Redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift).

```
update Table1 set gender = 
(
    select case when gender = 'male' then 'female'
                when gender = 'female' then 'male' end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way:

```
UPDATE users SET gender = IF(sex='Male','Female','Male');
```

definition:

> IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)